# Можно ли создать шаблон структуры внутри шаблона класса?

Tags: c++, классы, шаблоны-с++

У меня есть шаблон класса `BinarySearchTree`, внутри него я создаю структуры `Node`. `Node` должен быть такого же типа данных, как и `BinarySearchTree`. Но компилятору не нравится написание `Node<T>* = ...`, а если раскомментировать строчку перед `struct Node`, то будет ошибка, так как `T` определен выше.

```
#ifndef BINARYSEARCHTREE_H
#define BINARYSEARCHTREE_H

template <class T>
class BinarySearchTree {
public:

// здесь разные функции

private:
    // template <class T>
    struct Node {
        T key_;
        Node<T>* right_;
        Node<T>* left_;
        Node<T>* parent_;
        Node(T key, Node* right = nullptr, Node * left = nullptr, Node * parent = nullptr)
                : key_(key), right_(right), left_(left), parent_(parent)
        {}
    };
    Node<T>* root_;

    Node* iterativeSearchNode(const T& key) const;
};

template<class T>
BinarySearchTree<T>::Node *BinarySearchTree<T>::iterativeSearchNode(const T &key) const {
    Node* current = root_;
    while(current != nullptr) {
        if (key > current->key_) {
            current = current->right_;
        } else if (key < current->key_) {
            current = current->left_;
        } else {
            return current;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}

#endif
```

Если же убрать `<T>` везде, то у меня перестает работать функция, которая находится в private и возвращает 'Node'. Выдает такую ошибку `error: need 'typename' before 'BinarySearchTree<T>::Node' because 'BinarySearchTree<T>' is a dependent scope`

Comment: Попробуйте убрать из описания `Node` все эти `<T>`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте убрать из описания `Node` все эти `<T>`...

У вас `Node`, как сказать... Не слишком шаблонный, поскольку он `BinarySearchTree<T>::Node`, а не `BinarySearchTree<T>::Node<T>`.

Другое дело, если бы вам был нужен именно *шаблонный* `Node`. Тогда это бы имело вид типа

```
template <class U>
struct Node {
    U key_;
    Node* right_;
    Node* left_;
    Node* parent_;
    Node(U key, Node* right = nullptr, Node * left = nullptr, Node * parent = nullptr)
            : key_(key), right_(right), left_(left), parent_(parent)
    {}
};
Node<T>* root_;
Node<int>* iroot_;
```

Этот `Node<int>* iroot_;` добавлен просто чтоб показать, что вот так вы бы могли иметь разные `Node`, так как он был бы реально шаблонным классом.

**Update**

По поводу второй проблемы из комментария... Надо указать, что это именно тип:

```
template<class T>
typename BinarySearchTree<T>::Node * BinarySearchTree<T>::iterativeSearchNode(const T &key) const
{
```

или можно

```
template<class T>
auto BinarySearchTree<T>::iterativeSearchNode(const T &key) const -> BinarySearchTree<T>::Node *
{
```

Comment: Я пытался писать без `<T>`, но тогда возникает другая проблема с шаблоном, добавил в вопрос дополнительную информацию про ошибку, если писать без `<T>`

Comment: См. дополненный ответ.

Comment: конструктор `Node(T key, ...`  должен принимать тип U `Node(U key, ...)`

Comment: @ampawd Ну, теоретически не обязательно :)

Comment: @Harry честно говоря даже теоретического смысла не вижу писать T key. Такой код вызывает недоумение

Comment: @ampawd Хорошо, исправил. Все равно ведь вопрос не об этом :) Суть в том, как верно записать шаблонный класс внутри шаблонного класса, а что именно он из себя представляет — это вопрос второй...

Comment: @Harry ок, суть не в этом, ваш ответ в целом очень верный, но, согласитесь что все равно лучше видеть интуитивно более понятный код :) Node это же отдельный шаблонный класс внутри дерева. На мой взгляд по такому дизайну он не должен быть привязан к шаблонному параметру дерева

Comment: @ampawd Да без проблем, я просто даже не смотрел, что там и от чего вызывается...